# IValueConverter conversion error from string to boolean

Tags: c#, wpf

I have application written using MVVM pattern. I have a folder called enum where it displays the status either Enable or Disable. In my model, I declared the status property as boolean. The view is having a combobox which displays the status. Once the button is clicked it should save the status into the database as boolean data type. In order to make it work, I believe I should implement the IValueConverter class where it takes the String output and convert to boolean.

This is my model code:

```
private bool status;

    public bool ProductionLineStatus
    {
        get { return status; }
        set
        {
            status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductionLineStatus");
        }
    }
```

This is the converter:

```
public class StatusToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value == 1)
            {
                return "Enable";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Disable";
            }
        }
        return "Disable";

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (value.ToString())
        {
            case "Enable":
                return 1;
            case "Disable":
                return 0;
        }
        return 0;


    }
}
```

This is the xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <cv:StatusToBooleanConverter x:Key="statusToBooleanConverter"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="enum:Status"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox_status" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5.8,41.8,43.8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="combobox_status_SelectionChanged"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineStatus, Converter={StaticResource statusToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

How can i achieve my goal where I should be able to convert the value from string input to boolean input. Currently its showing me error message `Incorrect integer value ;True STATUS

Answer (score 0):

In your `switch` statement you are returning `1` if `Enabled` and `0` if `Disabled` in you `ConvertBack` Method, you cannot assign an integer value to a bool type. Instead do `return false` if `Disabled` and `return true` if `Enabled`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, It was my mistake. I had to change the code from the viewmodel.

The query should be converted from integer to boolean

Here is the code:

```
query = "Insert into productionlineconfig (PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE, PRODUCTION_LINE_NAME, PRODUCTION_LINE_STATUS) Values ('" + ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineCode + "' , '" + ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineName + "' , '" + Convert.ToInt32(ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineStatus) + "')";
```